# How does (--t) expression works in this code

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand how the math unfolds through this code, [easingDoc](https://github.com/danro/jquery-easing/blob/master/jquery.easing.js)

```js
function easeInOutQuad (t, b, c, d) {
        if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return c/2*t*t + b;
        return -c/2 * ((--t)*(t-2) - 1) + b;
    }
  
console.log(easeInOutQuad(0.3,50,150,1));
console.log(easeInOutQuad(0.95,50,150,1));
```

I am trying to decipher the equation for both the conditions. While I understand, the condition for **`if ((t/=d/2)`** from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15535967/11156131) describes what **`t/=d`** means and how it affects the calculation.

For example, **`(t/=d/2)<1`** the code can be rewritten as following and it would produce the identical result. Such as,

```js
function easeInOutQuad (t, b, c, d) {
        if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return c/2*t*t + b;
        return -c/2 * ((--t)*(t-2) - 1) + b;
    }
  

function alternate (t,b,c,d){
    if (2*t/d < 1) return c/2*(2*t/d)*(2*t/d)+b;
    return 999999;};

console.log(easeInOutQuad(0.3,50,150,1));
console.log(alternate(0.3,50,150,1)); //(150/2)*(2*0.3/1)*(2*0.3/1)+50
console.log(easeInOutQuad(0.45,50,150,1));
console.log(alternate(0.45,50,150,1));//(150/2)*(2*0.45/1)*(2*0.45/1)+50
```

I was wondering how can I express **`return -c/2 * ((--t)*(t-2) - 1) + b`** explicitly in equation like **`console.log(alternate(0.3,50,150,1)); //(150/2)*(2*0.3/1)*(2*0.3/1)+50`** so that I can undersatnd what the math is for that part.

Comment: That’s ridiculous code. `(t-1)*(t-3)` is a much more readable equivalent.

Comment: Some visual examples on https://easings.net/

Comment: Assigment expressions are equal to the resulting value. A lot of that code looks awful anyways.

Comment: @ Ry- thanks. `function alternate (t,b,c,d) {if (2*t/d < 1) return c/2*(2*t/d)*(2*t/d)+b; return -c/2 * ((2*t/d-1)*(2*t/d-3) - 1) + b;};}` is doing the job. Can you please explain how `(--t)*(t-2)` is equivalent to `(t-1)*(t-3)`. Thanks.

Comment: [MDN decrement operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Decrement)

Comment: @dippas I don't see that operator combination anywhere in the code shown, and that question looks to be the result of a simple misunderstanding. Seems unlikely to help the OP.

Comment: @miken32 its in the answer `It is the post decrement operator -- followed by the greater than operator >. Just the spacing is weird.`

Comment: @dippas I understand that. I just don't see how it answers the OP's rather unfocused (why I voted to close) question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the following 2 expressions could look tricky, here are the alternatives:

```
  c = -1 * c; // -c
  t = t - 1;  // --t
```

And an example for `-c/2 * ((--t)*(t-2) - 1) + b;`

```js
// -c/2 * ((--t)*(t-2) - 1) + b;
function alternate(t, b, c, d) {
  c = -1 * c; // -c
  t = t - 1;  // --t
  return (c / 2) * (t * (t - 2) - 1) + b;
};

console.log(alternate(0.3, 50, 150, 1));
console.log(((-1 * 150) / 2) * ((0.3 - 1) * ((0.3 - 1) - 2) - 1) + 50);
```